# Pumping Lemma for anb2n+1

Tags: pumping-lemma

I know how to solve pumping lemma for a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> :n>=0
But I don't understand how can I solve this example : a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>2n+1</sup> :n>=0

I tried to solve it but I am not sure that I have solved it correctly or not?Could somebody please help me here?

I can show how did I solve it. But seriously I am not sure is it correct or not. Could you please give me the correct one if I am wrong.

**Question :** Prove that a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>2n+1</sup> :n>=0 is not regular.

Here is my answer.

> Assume L is regular. Then pumping lemma must hold. Let m be an integer in Pumping lemma.
>
> Let w=a<sup>m</sup>b<sup>2m+1</sup> also in L. and |w|>=m
>
> By Pumping lemma w=xyz where |xy|<=m and |y|>=1
>
> According to pumping lemma w<sub>i</sub>=xy<sup>i</sup>z also in L for i=0,1,2,...
>
> Let i=2 then w<sub>2</sub>=xyyz.
>
> Let y=a<sup>k</sup> where 1<=k<=m and x=a<sup>q</sup> where 0<=q< m then z=a<sup>m-q-k</sup>b<sup>2m+1</sup>
>
> w<sub>2</sub>=xyyz = a<sup>q</sup>a<sup>k</sup>a<sup>k</sup>a<sup>m-q-k</sup>b<sup>2m+1</sup>
>
> = a<sup>m+k</sup>b<sup>2m+1</sup>
>
> but this is not in L for any value of 1<=k<=m
>
> So we have contradiction with pumping lemma. so, our assumption that L is regular is wrong. So, L can not be regular.

Is this correct???

Thank you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

x=a<sup>k</sup>
y=a<sup>j</sup>
z=a<sup>m-j-k</sup>b<sup>2m+1</sup>

Taking `i=m+2` you have:

a<sup>m+m+1</sup>b<sup>2m+1</sup>   ==> a<sup>2m+1</sup>b<sup>2m+1</sup> that isn't in L.

Answer (score -1):

> > > Pumping Lemma is used to prove that a Language is NOT REGULAR
> > >
> > > If A is a Regular Language, then A has a Pumping Length 'P' such
> > > that any string 'S where |S|>=P may be divided into 3 parts S=xyz such
> > > that the following conditions must be true:
> > >
> > > (1) xyz & A for every i>0
> > >
> > > (2) |y|>0
> > >
> > > (3) |xy| <=P
> > >
> > > To prove that a language is not Regular using PUMPING LEMMA, follow
> > > the below steps:
> > >
> > > (We prove using Contradiction) -> Assume that A is Regular
> > >
> > > -> It has to have a Pumping Length (say P)
> > >
> > > → All strings longer than P can be pumped |S|>=P -> Now find a string
> > > 'S' in A such that |S|>P
> > >
> > > -> Divide S into x y z
> > >
> > > -> Show that x y z & A for some i -> Then consider all ways that S can be divided into xyz
> > >
> > > -> Show that none of these can satisfy all the 3 pumping conditions at the same time →S cannot be Pumped == CONTRADICTION
> > >
> > > To prove this given expression is regular by a example:  Assume that
> > > A={a^nb^2n+1|n>=0} is regular  Pumping length=p
> > > |S|=3p+1>=p   |S|>=p   Divide s into x y z   Let p=3,and
> > > s=aaabbbbbbb
> > >
> > > **Case1:** The y is in a's part  a -> x  aa -> y  bbbbbbb  -> z   xy^iz
> > > i=2
> > > xy^2z=>a aaaa bbbbbbb
> > > xy^2z is not belongs to A
> > >
> > > **Case2:**  The y is in b's part   aaa -->x   bb --> y
> > > bbbbb -->z
> > > xy^iz
>
> i=2
> xy^2z=> aaa bbbb bbbbb
>
> > > xy^2z is not belongs to A
> > >
> > > **Case3:** The y is in both a and b parts    a-> x
> >
> > aabb ->y
> >
> > bbbbb -> z
> > xy^iz
> > i=2
> > xy^2z=> a aabbaabb bbbbb
> >
> > > xy^2z is not belongs to A */  we got contradiction Hence given
> > > expression is not regular
> > > FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING ABOUT PUMPING LEMMA PLEASE GO THROUGH THE LINK

https://youtu.be/Ty9tpikilAo

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).